# Azure PowerShell Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy command setting access policy to data factory

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

While trying to give access policy (Azure key vault) to my Azure data factory through PowerShell, I am getting error below:

> Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy : Operation returned an invalid status code
> 'BadRequest' At line:64 char:1
>
> - Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $keyvaultname -ServicePrincipal ...
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy], Gr     aphErrorException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.SetAzureKeyVau     ltAccessPolicy
>   ```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is the script I am trying to execute:

```
## select subcription

$subcription='Visual Studio Enterprise – MPN'

Select-AzSubscription $subcription


## create a new resource group

$resourcegroupname=”gho-rg-dev”
$location="eastus"

$rg=New-AzResourceGroup `
        -Name $resourcegroupname `
        -Location $location


## create the storage account


$storageAccountName = "ghostoragelab"
$skuName = "Standard_LRS"

$storageAccount = New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname `
                     -Name $storageAccountName `
                     -Location $location `
                     -SkuName $skuName

$storageaccountkey=(Get-AzStorageAccountkey -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -Name $storageAccount.StorageAccountName).Value[0]


##create azure data factory

$datafactoryname='lab-factory-dev'

$df= New-AzDataFactoryV2 `
        -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -Name $datafactoryname -Location $location




## creating the azure key vault

$keyvaultname="labkeydev"

$keyvault=New-AzKeyVault -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -Name $keyvaultname `
        -Location $location

# creating the secret key in keyvault

Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultname -Name "secret-access-key"`
 -SecretValue(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $storageaccountkey -AsPlainText -Force)

#Give access policy to the datafactory thorugh keyvault

*## this is where script is failing*

Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $keyvaultname -ServicePrincipalName $df.DataFactoryId -PermissionsToSecrets Get
```

Comment: Can you post the code you tried ? It can help more.

Comment: Please provide your complete command here.

Comment: Added the script that i was trying to execute through powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to add the [MSI (Managed Service Identity) of the Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity) to the `Access policies` of your keyvault.

You got the error because you used the `-ServicePrincipalName $df.DataFactoryId` in this
command `Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy`, the `$df.DataFactoryId` is the `resource id` of the data factory, what you need is the `Application ID(Client ID)` of the MSI.

So if you want to use `-ServicePrincipalName` parameter, your command should be:

```
$appId = (Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $df.Identity.PrincipalId).ApplicationId
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName joykeyvault -ServicePrincipalName $appId -PermissionsToSecrets get
```

---

The command above needs the permission to get service principal in your Azure AD. If you don't have this permission, you could use the command (I recommend you to use this one):

```
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName joykeyvault -ObjectId $df.Identity.PrincipalId -PermissionsToSecrets get -BypassObjectIdValidation
```

If your data factory has already been created, you could use `Get-AzDataFactoryV2` to get it, then add it to the access policies.

```
$datafactory = Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName <group name> -Name <factory name>
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName joykeyvault -ObjectId $datafactory.Identity.PrincipalId -PermissionsToSecrets get -BypassObjectIdValidation
```

[image]

Comment: If i want to add user to access policy in the keyvault ?

Comment: @Ghousethanedar If you want to add the user, you need to pass the objectid of the user in azure ad to the -Objectid parameter.

Comment: @ Joy Wang could you please help me with the command syntax that would be helpfull

Comment: @Ghousethanedar Try :`$Id = (Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com).Id`, 
`Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName joykeyvault -ObjectId $Id -PermissionsToSecrets get -BypassObjectIdValidation`